# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Already done a research but I don't find the right answer that fit my problem.

error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given(create.blade)

```
<div class="an-single-component with-shadow">
      <div class="an-component-body">

        @foreach($setting as $setfield)
          @if($setfield->type === 'smallInteger')
            <div class"form-group" style="padding:20px">
              <div style="display:inline-block">
                  <P><input type="hidden" name="set_id[{{$setfield->code}}]" value="{{$setfield->id}}">{{$setfield->display_name}}</P>
              </div>
              <div class="an-switch-box-wrapper pull-right" style="display:inline-block">
                  <div class="lcs_wrap">{{ Form::checkbox($setfield->code, '1', true) }}
                      <div class="lcs_switch lcs_checkbox_switch lcs_on">
                          <div class="lcs_cursor"></div>
                          <div class="lcs_label lcs_label_on">ON</div>
                          <div class="lcs_label lcs_label_off">OFF</div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>

          @elseif($setfield->type === 'string')
            <div class"form-group" style="padding:20px">
              <div style="display:inline-block">
                  <P><input type="hidden" name="set_id[{{$setfield->code}}]" value="{{$setfield->id}}">{{$setfield->display_name}}</P>
              </div>
              <div class="an-switch-box-wrapper pull-right" style="display:inline-block">
              {!!Form::text($setfield->code,old($setfield->code),['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width: 100%'])!!}
              </div>
          </div>

          @elseif($setfield->type === 'integer')
            <div class"form-group" style="padding:20px">
              <div style="display:inline-block">
                  <P><input type="hidden" name="set_id[{{$setfield->code}}]" value="{{$setfield->id}}">{{$setfield->display_name}}</P>
              </div>
              <div class="an-switch-box-wrapper pull-right" style="display:inline-block">
              {!!Form::text($setfield->code,old($setfield->code),['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width: 100%'])!!}
              </div>
          </div>

          @elseif($setfield->type === 'date')
            <div class"form-group" style="padding:20px">
              <div style="display:inline-block">
                  <P><input type="hidden" name="set_id[{{$setfield->code}}]" value="{{$setfield->id}}">{{$setfield->display_name}}</P>
              </div>
              <div class="an-switch-box-wrapper pull-right" style="display:inline-block">
              {!!Form::date($setfield->code,old($setfield->code),['class'=>'form-control','style'=>'width: 100%'])!!}
              </div>
          </div>

          @endif
        @endforeach

      </div>
    </div> <!-- end .AN-SINGLE-COMPONENT -->
```

When I do `dd($request->all())` I got all the data but when I click submit the error will occur.

Comment: Check you data once again ? like for `$setfield->code` ?

Comment: i used $setfield->code to make a reference like code = settings id..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Laravel specific error:

in php documents if you see

```
htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

this function accepts, 2 parameters, first one is a string and second is an optional parameter.

If you have an array of strings to be escaped then use **foreach** and escape each string

Answer (score 0):

There is an array anywhere in one of your Blade {{}}, please check them.

Read: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

You are using Array inside {{}} somewhere.
You can only use String inside {{}}.

use {{dd(variable_name)}} to check the variable before you use it inside {{}}.
if its an array convert it into String first ( using implode()) ).

implode documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

blade documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data